# ColorRamp following musgrave islands

Tags: texturing, materials, shaders, path, procedural

I'm trying to create islands using musgrave texture and i would like the ColorRamp colors to follow the shape of the islands that musgrave texture does.

for now i got this:

[image]
[image]

but i would like something like this (will manage colors later):

[image]

Can you guys tells me if it is possible and how to achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works just like you described :).
You're just mixing two different Musgrave textures (one is set to 2D and one to 3D)

Use the same texture and it will work.

[image]

Comment: short and sweet! thanks!